# Having expected doctrine entities in seperate file when testing repositories

Tags: php, testing, doctrine, phpunit, fixtures

Ok so in my tests, I load my fixtures with the help of the `doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle`.
All I wanna do is basically load the fixtures and then compare to a "set" entity. But I wanna have this "set" entity in a seperate file, not the in the corresponding method. What's the best way to load those entities from a seperate file and then compare them to the one I just created trough the fixtures?

Comment: It sounds like you want to test your data fixtures, but why?

Comment: I know it sounds stupid, but I basically wanna (or have to) test the entities setters/getters